# Поиск с условием

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, можно ли с помощью какого-нибудь селектора с использованием .find найти и скрыть блоки с несоответствующим значением в .data().

```
<div class="block">
    <div data-name="nama1">1</div>
    <div data-name="nama2">2</div>
    <div data-name="nama1">1</div>
    <div data-name="nama4">4</div>
</div>

$(document).on('click', '.class', function() {
    var name = 'nama1';
    $('.block').find('[data-name="НЕ РАВНА nama1"]').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для эти целей можно использовать 2 способа в jQuery:

[Selector :not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) и код будет выглядеть так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class-one', function() {
    $('.block').find('div').not('[data-name="nama1"]').hide();
});
```

[Функция .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) и код будет выглядеть так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class-two', function() {
    $('.block').find('div:not([data-name="nama1"])').hide();
});
```

[Пример использования](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/rjs1pd44/)

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```
$('.block').find('[data-name!="НЕ РАВНА nama1"]').hide();
```